# is there anyway to see logs of a specific app in android and save theme in a file in storage?

Tags: android, react-native, logcat

i have an **react native** app and right now there is no way that i could use crashlytics in my application, my app crashes with no message on different situations, i need some logs from logcat to know what causes the crashes.

there are some question from couple of years ago suggesting applications from play store but they need a rooted system apparently or they need phone to be connected to adb. i can not do any of these solutions.
so if there is anyway to **save the logs** on phone storage help me with that

Answer (score 0):

You can configure **Sentry** in your project through [documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/) and you will get feedback every crash with details, it's very helpful.

Beside that you can see all logs through **Powershell**, just open the app and linked with usb to the laptop, then open **Powershell** and tap :

> adb logcat

Hope that help you, Thanks.